# Differences between aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp vs aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

What are the diferrences the aws maven dependencies aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp vs aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp is the SDK for Cognito User pools feature, which helps you to create and maintain a user directory and add sign-up and sign-in to your mobile app or web application. aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity is for Cognito federated identity, which vends a unique identity and temporary scoped aws credentials to the federated users or guest users of your app.